# How is S3 bucket name being derived in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I've this cloudformation script template.js that creates a bucket. I'm bit unsure how the bucket name is being assembled.

Assuming my stackname is `my-service` I'm getting bucket name created as `my-service-s3bucket-1p3s4szy5bomf`

1. I want to know how this name was derived
2. I also want to get rid of that arn at the end. `-1p3s4szy5bomf`
3. Can I skip Outputs at the end, Not sure what they do

Code in template.js

```
var stackTemplate = {

    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "with S3",
    "Resources": {
        "S3Bucket": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
            "Properties": {},
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                    "id": "bba483af-4ae6-4d3d-b37d-435f66c42e44"
                }
            }
        },
        "S3BucketAccessPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyName": "S3BucketAccessPolicy",
                "Roles": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "IAMServiceRole"
                    }
                ],
                "PolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "s3:DeleteObject",
                                "s3:GetObject",
                                "s3:PutObject",
                                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                                "s3:List*"
                            ],
                            "Resource": [
                                {
                                    "Fn::Sub": [
                                        "${S3BucketArn}",
                                        {
                                            "S3BucketArn": {
                                                "Fn::GetAtt": ["S3Bucket", "Arn"]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "Fn::Sub": [
                                        "${S3BucketArn}/*",
                                        {
                                            "S3BucketArn": {
                                                "Fn::GetAtt": ["S3Bucket", "Arn"]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "s3Bucket": {
            "Description": "The created S3 bucket.",
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "S3Bucket"
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-S3Bucket"
                }
            }
        },
        "s3BucketArn": {
            "Description": "The ARN of the created S3 bucket.",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": ["S3Bucket", "Arn"]
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-S3BucketArn"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

stackUtils.assembleStackTemplate(stackTemplate, module);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I want to know how this name was derived
```

If you don't specify a name for your bucket, CloudFormation generate a new one based on the pattern  **$name-of-stack-s3bucket-$generatedId**
from documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-s3-bucket.html
BucketName
A name for the bucket. If you don't specify a name, AWS CloudFormation generates a unique ID and uses that ID for the bucket name.

```
I also want to get rid of that arn at the end. -1p3s4szy5bomf
```

You can assign a name of you bucket, but AWS recommand to let it empty to generate a new one, to avoid creation with the same name (stackset...) by CloudFormation example :

```
"Resources": {
        "S3Bucket": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
            "Properties": {
               "BucketName": "DesiredNameOfBucket" <== 
                },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                    "id": "bba483af-4ae6-4d3d-b37d-435f66c42e44"
                }
            }
        },

Can I skip Outputs at the end, Not sure what they do
```

It is used to have the information, name and the ARN of the bucket created, if you want you can delete the Outputs part from your template

Comment: great insights. I don;t want to use autogenerated name bcz if that unique id at end changes my code will break

Comment: that means in your template you must assign a name, I will change my answer to present the code

Comment: done  @Ajeetkumar

Comment: Will run and update you

Comment: okay @Ajeetkumar, you can upvote and accept the question if its resolve your problem otherwise let me know

Comment: It's been great help @Hatim

Comment: good to hear that @Ajeetkumar !